# Zbar wantsFullScreenLayout=NO maked imagePickerView to shift

Tags: iphone, ios, statusbar, zbar-sdk

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev,

I'm using Zbar QR code scanner in my app. I've setting wantsFullScreenLayout = NO; so the status bar becomes visible. But the int the result I'm getting the ImagePickerView of Zbar shifted to the top with the size of status bar, i.e. in the button I'm getting gray rectangle

My code is following,

```
mReader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
mReader.readerDelegate = self;
mReader.showsZBarControls = NO;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
mReader.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
mReader.readerView.torchMode = 0;
mReader.readerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height);
```

How to get rid of gray rectangle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys, really a newbie mistake, basically I also need to set the correct size to my self.view . 
After doing this, my problem is gone,

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height);
```